# Handle a specific error in golang

Tags: csv, go, error-handling

I am trying to simply ignore the `csv.ErrFieldCount` error in our code but cannot seem to only look at that one error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
record, err := reader.Read()
if err != nil {
    if err == csv.ErrFieldCount {
        return nil
    }
    return err
}
```

But when I run the code the last line of the csv file gives me this error paniced `line 11535, column 0: wrong number of fields in line`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`csv.Reader` doesn't return that error, it returns a [`csv.ParseError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#ParseError). You first need to check if you have a ParseError, then check the Err field:

```
if err, ok := err.(*csv.ParseError); ok && err.Err == csv.ErrFieldCount {
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Set FieldsPerRecord in the CSV Reader struct to be a negative number.  Then ParseErrors for unequal field counts will not occur.

See here:

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#example_Reader_options

Answer (score 9):

Yeah its not really *well* documented (that is, glancing at the documentation doesn't give you the answer very quickly). Although `Read()` returns an `error`, its actually an instance of a [*csv.ParseError](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#ParseError) which you can assert and check:

```
record, err := reader.Read()
if err != nil {
    if perr, ok := err.(*csv.ParseError); ok && perr.Err == csv.ErrFieldCount {
        return nil
    }
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Go 1.13 I think the idiomatic way to handle this would be to use [`errors.Is`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors?utm_source=godoc#Is):

```golang
if errors.Is(err, csv.ErrFieldCount) {
    return nil
}
```

See [Working with Errors in Go 1.13](https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors) for more details.