# How to parse MySQL errors

Tags: mysql, go, error-handling

I am trying to parse MySQL errors in order to return clean error messages to the user from a Go API.

I read some article like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008600/handle-a-specific-error-in-golang) that show what I would like to do but it looks like the module [go-mysql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) that I am using doesn't support parseError.

To give a concrete example, with the error:

```
Error 1062: Duplicate entry 'John' for key 'name_UNIQUE'
```

I would like to be able to build a data structure that allow me to organize the information in order to return a user friendly message like

```
Error with the field 'name': 'John' already exist"
```

so I can also translate it in different languages and send ready-to-use error messages back to the client.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what made you think a MySQL driver would return a CSV Reader error code.

Comment: So, how does app usually do to print a nice message to the user? I mean, there are thousands of possible errors...

Comment: @Adrien Why would you tell the user about the mysql error at all? Usually you log the real error and send something to "Internal Server Error" to the user. You should not rely on MySQL errors to do validations for you. Your application code should already check for duplicates etc.

Comment: @DanieleTesta I guess it would depend on the application. I would believe it is less efficient to query the database twice to check if something exists, and then inserting, rather than just inserting and returning a 409 from an error message I can easily parse. In my case, the database is the bottleneck, therefore I try to be mindful of the number of queries I do :)

Comment: @Adrien Actually, in my experience, it's much heavier on the database to have a UNIQUE index (which you have to, to make your solution work) than to not have it and do an extra SELECT query before inserting.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found some hints in [packets.go](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/4ac31a97ccff97de60ba3c630bfb4733c1bb6d0e/packets.go#L543) and [driver_test.go](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/8f6c67f0228a4a6a962008d6c3d1e694e4532e71/driver_test.go#L1157)

Example:

```
me, ok := err.(*mysql.MySQLError)
if !ok {
    return err
}
if me.Number == 1062 {
    return errors.New("It already exists in a database.")
}
return err
```

Possible values of `me.Number` can be found in [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html)

Comment: You can also use the short form `if err.(*mysql.MySQLError).Number == MYSQL_KEY_EXITS { ... }` (here with a const/define for `1062`)

Comment: Been looking for this info for about an hour, thanks for the answer! Also found the [MySQLError](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql?tab=doc#MySQLError) godoc

Answer (score -5):

That error comes directly from the server, pretty much you would have to parse the error string (`err.Error()`) yourself.

Comment: @Adrien sadly not really, you would have to find a list of all mysql errors and have a different parser (or regexp) for each code.

Comment: Why is this down-voted, It is the only correct answer. As you need to grab info from the string (field names, etc.) which is not present in the error number (obviously). Not liking an answer (that is correct) is no reason to down vote...